# java Method.invoke(): how to check if valid jar is specified?

Tags: java, reflection, jar, swt

I am using the load an appropriate SWT library dynamically using the code in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3204032/1360074) .

```
Method addUrlMethod = URLClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", URL.class);
addUrlMethod.setAccessible(true);
....
URL swtFileUrl = new URL("rsrc:" + swtFileName);
addUrlMethod.invoke(classLoader, swtFileUrl);
```

Now just for experiment I change swt_win32_x86.jar file into an empty file. But line "addUrlMethod.invoke(classLoader, swtFileUrl);" does not throw any kind of exception.

Why is it so? And how can check whether the swtFileName is a valid SWT library file or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is it so?

If you look at `URLClassLoader.addURL`, it only adds the argument to the list of URLs to search.

> And how can check whether the swtFileName is a valid SWT library file or not?

Try to load a class which should be there:

```
try {
    classLoader.loadClass("org.eclipse.swt.SWT");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Alexey, do you mean class.forName("")? I don't find any classForName in ClassLoader class.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `classLoader.loadClass`. `Class.forName` should work as well.