# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load 32-bit SWT libraries on 64-bit JVM in windows

Tags: java, swt, install4j, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am developing a windows application.

I need to create an installer(a common installer for both 32 bit and 64 bit windows OS) for that, for that I am using Install4J software.

I developed in Windows 32 bit, jdk 1.7.

Installer working fine in 32 bit windows os, but when I try to create installer in win 64 bit os, it is throwing me an error like  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load 32-bit SWT libraries on 64-bit JVM

Please help to sort out this..

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that there are separate "swt.jar" files for 32bit and 64bit Windows JVMs, and they are not interchangeable.  You can't use the 32bit Windows JAR on a 64bit Windows JVM ... or the other way around.  (AFAIK, the fundamental impediment is in Windows and the JVM rather than SWT.)

One possibility is to do some classloader tricks, and dynamically choose between different JARs depending on the platform that your app detects at runtime.  The installer would need incorporate both flavours of the SWT JAR ... with different names.

This answer goes into more detail:  [Supporting SWT on Windows/Mac & 32bit/64bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14144232/supporting-swt-on-windows-mac-32bit-64bit)

Comment: I have downloaded the swt for 64 bit from this URL http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.6.1-201009090800/index.php#SWT still getting the same error as befor

Comment: Are you sure you put it into the installer?

Answer (score 0):

Well that is just because when u install program into the Program files that will install only 32-but and will load 32-bit libraries so u can do one thing very simple solution of that just install your program in the the `Program files x86 if u have 64  bit system.`

that work for me and might work for u too.