# SWT: Running an application developed on OSX in Windows

Tags: java, windows, macos, swt, cross-platform

I have an SWT application that I've developed on OSX, so it contains the Mac version of the SWT libraries.

Now I need to run this application on a Windows machine. I export the application to a .jar file, but when I attempt to execute the jar in Windows, I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoa
der.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons:

    no swt-cocoa-4236 in java.library.path
    no swt-cocoa in java.library.path
    Can't load library: \\psf\Home\.swt\lib\win32\x86\swt-cocoa-4236.dll
    Can't load library: \\psf\Home\.swt\lib\win32\x86\swt-cocoa.dll

    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at display.StoragePickupDisplay.open(StoragePickupDisplay.java:70)
    at display.StoragePickupDisplay.main(StoragePickupDisplay.java:58)
    ... 5 more
```

I have added the Windows version of SWT libraries but that didn't make a difference. I need the Mac libraries to be in there for continued development. How can I get around this?

Comment: From this error log I understand that you do not have the necessary jars in your java path ? Where is your java path in your Windows env.? Try to copy the necessary jars to your windows path or try to add them to your build path.

Comment: Did you set CLASSPATH in windows? If you set it probably you didn't add your jar files to class path. Already it saying: "Could not load SWT library." And there is no difference between java libraries. Every library works in mac, linux and windows. Because they're working on JVM.

Comment: @kodmanyagha Wrong, SWT is platform dependent, since it uses OS native code. You have to supply the correct version of the library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add the correct `SWT.jar` to the classpath. You can download them [here](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/).

If you are deploying for Windows, you will have to bundle the swt jar for Windows (either 32bit or 64bit depending on the system).

If you want to create an application that runs on all platforms, have a look at this post:

[Create cross platform Java SWT Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706222/create-cross-platform-java-swt-application/3204032#3204032)

Comment: Is there a way to add both libraries, but then to dynamically tell it to not load one of them based on the OS?

Comment: @JamesHarpe That's exactly what's happening in the answer I linked to.