# Java SWT: Compiling application for 64 bit JVM on a 32 bit system

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, 32bit-64bit

I'm trying to write a SWT app in Eclipse, in a 32 bits Ubuntu 12.04 system. It works fine but when I try to execute it on my 64 bit Windows 7 system, I get an error: cannot load 32-bit swt libraries on 64-bit jvm

Well, the problem is pretty clear. But, what can I do about it? Can I build a 64 bit version of my program on a 32 bit system, or do I really need to get a 64 bit Ubuntu set up just for this?

Comment: Have a look at the accepted answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706222/create-cross-platform-java-swt-application) question.

Comment: Wow, interesting, but I was hoping for a simpler and quicker fix. Thank you very much anyways. I guess my question has no reason for being here any longer then.

Comment: A quicker solution would be to exchange the 32bit swt.jar in your final jar with the 64bit swt.jar

Comment: That hack worked. A bit dirty but quick! Thanks

Comment: Mind if I post it as an answer?

Comment: Well I just saw that is really unnecesary. If I copy SWT JAR in my windows system it works without having to do anything.

Comment: Oh, well. Even better :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions:

- Long and correct: http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#multiplatformjar
- Quick hack: download a 64 bits Windows (or whatever SO you are running) version of SWT and copy the swt.jar file into %JAVA_HOME%\lib\ext directory (C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\ext by default in Windows). Then just execute the JAR and it will run, even if the packaged SWT library is for another system.

Some more details here:
http://spacesciencesoftware.wordpress.com/2013/08/29/building-a-64-bits-java-swt-application-in-a-32-bits-system/

Comment: Please never just post a link. When the link becomes unreachable, your answer will be useless. Add a summary here as well.