# Application to decide the jar version

Tags: java, swt, classloader

I've created a stand-along swt application. I've used the 32 bit jars for the application. When I transfered the application to 64 bit jvm I got the unstaisfied linker errors. So I used the 64 bit jars.

I need the application to decide the jars either 64 bit or 32 bit based on the jvm version. I'm able to find the jvm version using the System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model"), using this can I choose the jars to load into the memory.

Comment: Maybe you need to write a custom classloader for this.

Comment: Give error logs please

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create cross platform Java SWT Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706222/create-cross-platform-java-swt-application)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can make your application dynamically be able to select an appropriate version of the jar . Its over a good thing to do as it ensures portability of your application .

Check this [Select correct jar for your jvm at runtime](http://www.chrisnewland.com/select-correct-swt-jar-for-your-os-and-jvm-at-runtime-191)

Comment: I've used the following methodology i.e., The classpath will contain both the 64 bit and 32 bit jars, I've read the classpath and removed the 32 bit libraries if it is a 64 bit machine and vice versa, and replaced with the application class path. Will that work.

Comment: isnt it better to pack both 32 & 64 bits versions of the jars . DOnt remove anything just let the application figure out which one to call after querying the os.arch property . Your method u will need to test it out  .

Comment: how to implement that version which you have mentioned

Comment: @wekselva what part did you not understand ? You need to implement the functions that are listed ..