# Start youtube Video with JWebBrowser

Tags: java, youtube, djnativeswing, jwebbrowser

I have embedded a youtube video as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20440484/embed-a-youtube-video-to-jframe?answertab=votes#tab-top) in my java application. But I want the video to start without clicking on play. It should start asap. I looked for something like webBrowser.play() or webbrowser.click() but was not succesful.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try adding autoplay to the URL you're embedding? `&autoplay=1`

Comment: yepp.. that worked. I feel quite stupid right now. Anyway thanks!