# Java Swing: focus JWebBrowser and press space when button is pressed

Tags: java, swing, youtube, djnativeswing, jwebbrowser

I have embedded a youtube video as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20440484/embed-a-youtube-video-to-jframe?answertab=votes#tab-top). I have several videos and when one finishes the next one starts automatically. I achieved this by looking up the video duration and starting a TimerTask.

Now there is one problem left: If the user pauses the youtube video, the timer continues and the next video starts after some time.
I thought of this solution but could not make it happen: Implement a JButton, that stops the timer, changes the focus to the youtube video and presses the space button. That should stop the video.
I played with the JWebBrowser.grabFocus() and alike but I was not succesful.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: requestFocusInWindow?

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes I tried that too but it does not work. When I do webBrowser.requestFocusInWindows() and press space, nothing happens. But when I click on the youtube video and then press space the video stops.
I also tried webBrowserPanel.requestFocusInWindows()

Comment: Requesting focus on the component may not give focus to the you tube video element, unless the `JWebBrowser` component provides you a means to focus a given element, I don't think you'll get much luck