# Flash-embedded videos are no longer supported

Tags: java, eclipse, youtube

I'm working in a project of making clients. I wanted to make a Youtube Viewer Frame and followed the tips at [Embed a YouTube video to JFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20440484/embed-a-youtube-video-to-jframe). However, the result is *"Flash-embedded videos are no longer supported!"*.

So what can I do now to create a Youtube Viewer with Java Swing ?

Thank you so much !

```
public static JPanel getBrowserPanel() {
    JPanel webBrowserPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JWebBrowser webBrowser = new JWebBrowser();
    webBrowserPanel.add(webBrowser, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    webBrowser.setBarsVisible(false);
    webBrowser.navigate("https://www.youtube.com/v/b-Cr0EWwaTk?fs=1");
    return webBrowserPanel;
}
```

Comment: JavaFX and [JFXPanel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html) would be your friend..

Comment: I dont want to use JavaFX, because ..... I dont like :) and it's more difficult to use than JavaSwing. So do you have a better idea with JSW ?

Comment: I don't know any other best way to do it.. JavaFX will fix all the issue..and I don't like my boss but still :p

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you’ve encountered regarding the error message that you receive while using the program may be caused by the add-ins. To sort out your concern, we suggest that you download the additional program provided on this link. Once you’re on the page, you may click the Shockwave Flash Player button under the PowerPoint 2010 section. It will take you to the manufacturer’s website, go to the bottom of the page, and then click the Shockwave Player button under the Download section. Click the Download now button and follow the on-screen instructions to complete the process. Once you’re done you may check if the issue persists.

Additionally, if the issue continues, you may run the Repair option from the Control Panel. This process will scan and correct any possible cause of the issue. To do this, you may follow the steps provided in this article on how to repair an Office application. Choose which operating system are you using and proceed with the steps under the Repair Office from the Control Panel section, and then complete the process.

Keep us updated about your concern for additional.